# Display Number up to two decimal point error

Tags: php, xml, curl, number-formatting

I want to dislay the number up to 2 decimal point the output is coming from the xml file  through curl function. I tried the number_format, printf('%.2f',$number)and sprintf() functon.these are displaying the result 0.00.The code is following.

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, `http://orbisadvisors.redinews.com/tools/XM01?                                                                                                      queryid=QJ33020&fields=Last&fields=Change&fields=Chperc&symbol=BSZ`);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $sp= curl_exec ($ch);
  $sp1=explode(" ",$sp);
  echo "????".$lsp1=$sp1[4];
  printf("%.2f",$lsp1);
  print_r($sp1);
  curl_close ($ch);
```

In case I use the static number in place of the variable .It is giving the correct result.

Thanks

Comment: I check the type of the output that is in string type.How can I change it string to float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a library like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML) to parse the XML data that you're receiving, like the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://orbisadvisors.redinews.com/tools/XM01?queryid=QJ33020&fields=Last&fields=Change&fields=Chperc&symbol=BSZ');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$sp= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);    

$xml = simplexml_load_string($sp);
$last = sprintf("+%.2f", $xml->Stock->Last); // 1280.70
```

Comment: Thanks.I am also want to agsign the '+' and '-' sign regarding the value If value is + then + sign else - sign.

Comment: @RohitSharma: You just need to add a plus sign (`+`) in the format string. I updated my answer to include this.